Does there exist a model of ZF in which every linear functional on $\prod_{n \in \Bbb N} \Bbb F_2$ is continuous?
I should preface this question by saying that I know almost no serious set theory.
Inspired by an answer of mine I got curious about a set-theoretic problem: Equip the $\Bbb F_2$ vector space $\prod_{n \in \Bbb N} \Bbb F_2$ with the product topology. Is there a model of ZF where every linear map $\prod_{n \in \Bbb N} \Bbb F_2 \to \Bbb F_2$ is continuous?
The motivation for this question comes from the linked answer: there I used an a choice-dependent argument to produce a discontinuous functional on this vector space to give an example of a finite index group in a profinite group that is not open. The problem of finding such examples is relevant (among other things) because a celebrated theorem (using the classification of finite simple groups!) says that there are no such examples for topologically finitely generated profinite groups. Asking for every finite index subgroup of a profinite group to be open is equivalent to asking if a group is its own profinite completion (as an abstract group), which is a natural question to ask about profinite groups.
What I have tried (despite knowing no set theory): I have a feeling this might be related to ultrafilters, i.e. that in a model of ZF with no non-principal ultrafilters there might be no discontinuous functional. The reason I believe this is that if we consider $\prod_{n \in \Bbb N} \Bbb F_2$ as a ring with pointwise multiplication, then multiplicative functionals $\prod_{n \in \Bbb N} \Bbb F_2 \to \Bbb F_2$ correspond to ultrafilters and continuous ones correspond (I think) to principal ultrafilters. But of course this isn't an answer, as not every functional is multiplicative.

I changed the tag from reverse-math to descriptive-set-theory since reverse mathematics is about subsystems of second-order arithmetic, which is not about your question. Descriptive set theory works on Polish spaces, and $\mathbb{F}_2^\omega$ can be seen as a Polish space (i.e., the Cantor space.)

Posting as a comment since I am not sure if I'm using a bit of AC somewhere. Work in a model in which all subsets of Polish spaces have the BP, I'll show that if $f\colon 2^\omega\to 2$ is a linear functional then it must be continuous. Suppose not, then $\ker(f)$ is a subgroup of $2^\omega$ with the BP. If it is meager we have that $2^\omega$ is the union of two meager sets, a contradiction. If $\ker(f)$ is not Meager, then $\ker(f)^{-1}\ker(f)=\ker(f)$ is open by Pettis lemma, hence clopen, hence $f$ is continuous, also a contradiction.

We can have DC while all subsets of $2^\omega$ have the BP, and I believe that DC is enough to get Pettis lemma, the fact that a Polish space is not the union of two meager sets, and that a functional with closed kernel is continuous, but I didn't check carefully.

I have no idea if it is related to ultrafilters (although it sounds plausible that if the ultrafilter lemma holds, then there is a discontinuous linear functional from $\mathbb{F}_2^\omega$ to $\mathbb{F}_2$) but let me prove that Solovay model thinks every linear functional $\mathbb{F}_2^\omega \to \mathbb{F}_2$ is continuous.
We can equip $\mathbb{F}_2^\omega$ a natural topology making the vector space homeomorphic to the Cantor space. Its topology is generated by $B_s$ for $s\in \mathbb{F}_2^{<\omega}$, where $$B_s = \{v\in \mathbb{F}_2^\omega\mid s\subseteq v\}.$$
We can impose a complete measure (whose construction is similar to that of Lebesgue measure over $[0,1]$) $\mu$ satisfying $\mu(B_s)=2^{-|s|}$. It is known that Solovay model satisfies $\mathsf{ZF+DC}$ and every subset of $\mathbb{F}_2^\omega$ is $\mu$-measurable. $\mu$ also enjoys various properties what Lebesgue measure has.
We claim (over $\mathsf{ZF+DC}$) that if a linear functional $F\colon \mathbb{F}_2^\omega \to \mathbb{F}_2$ is $\mu$-measurable, then it is continuous at the zero vector, which implies the continuity of $F$. Its proof is more or less similar to the real number case, but let me rephrase in our setting.
By Lusin's theorem, we have a compact set $K\subseteq \mathbb{F}_2^\omega$ such that $\mu(K)>2/3$ and $F$ is uniformly continuous over $K$. Thus we can pick $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $x\restriction n=y\restriction n$, then $F(x)=F(y)$ for $x,y\in K$.
Now let $z\in\mathbb{F}^\omega_2$ be any vector such that the first $n$ components are zero.
Then we can see that $K \cap (K+z)\neq\varnothing$, otherwise we have a contradiction by the following inequality:
$$1 = \mu(\mathbb{F}^\omega_2)\ge \mu(K)+\mu(K+z)\ge 4/3.$$
Hence we can find $x_0\in K\cap (K+z)$, so $x_0+z\in K$. It shows $F(x_0)=F(x_0+z)$, so $F(z)=0$.
In sum, we found $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $z\in\mathbb{F}^\omega_2$, if $z\restriction n = \mathbf{0}\restriction n$, then $F(z)=0$, which is the definition of the continuity of $F$.

Thanks for the answer! Yes, I think I can prove that the ultrafilter lemma implies the existence of a discontinuous functional: Take $\mathcal U$ a non-trivial ultrafilter. Then because $\beta \Bbb N \cong \mathrm{Spec}(\prod_{\Bbb N} \Bbb F_2)$, this gives a non-principal maximal ideal inside the ring $\prod_{\Bbb N} \Bbb F_2$. The quotient is isomorphic to $\Bbb F_2$, because the quotient is a field where every element is idempotent. Using the fact that $\bigoplus_{\Bbb N}\Bbb F_2$ is dense in $\Bbb F_2$,, it's not hard to show that this is discontinuous.
